# Junos HTTP reverse proxy forwarded based on HTTP host

Tags: juniper-junos, proxy

How do I configure AppSecure to function as a reverse proxy for my web servers based on the HTTP host header field?

E.g. website1.domain.com and website2.domain.com should be reverse proxied to different internal servers from the same public IP address.

I've search and searched and cannot find any documentation for this. I don't see anything in J-Web and the CLI is unhelpful for AppSecure.